# SD Card vanished after placement of .nomedia file

Tags: mount, sd-card, find, format

This is not really a Ubuntu problem but since I moved from Windows to Ubuntu I naturally would like to use Ubuntu to solve this problem.

I bought a 32gb sandisk micro sd card for my galaxy note 2. Everyrhing worked fine and I started adding files to it. After a couple of files (music, pictures abd docs) were added I realized that many of them appeared in the gallery.  This became annoying because I did not want all of them to appear there. I usually use a .nomedia file placed in the folder I want to exclude to manage the media flood in the gallery.

Since I put a whole lot of media onto the new sd card I thought it wont hurt if I place the .nomedia file directly in the root of the sd card. And so I did. Seconds later the sd card vanished from android altogether.

Plugged it into the card reader on my windows laptop. A removable disk appears in the file tree but when I clicked on it it only told me to please add some media into drive.

Ubuntu it doesnt even show at all. If I plug in anothervsd card it pops up fine.

So I tried finding it. I plugged it back the card reader on my machine running ubuntu and typed sudo fdisk -l. It listed it once as dev/sdb I tried mounting it into media/sdcard

But for whatever reason my laptop hung itself shortly afterwards.

Now when I type fdisk -l the disk doesn't even appear anymore.

PLease someone help me out here.

Don't care about the data on the card but would like to use the card again.  So I'm trying to find acway how to format it and make it usable again using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you download and install gparted from the Software Centre, that should help you recover or reformat the usb drive and hopefully its contents.